# I am Attempting to Interweave Two One Dimensional Arrays Into a New Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to take two one dimensional arrays and interweave them in a new array. For example

```
a = (1,2,3) & b = (44,55,66,77,88)
```

taking these two arrays and interweaving them to make

```
c = (1,44,2,55,3,66,77,88)
```

I sincerely believed I have solved it but I cannot figure out why this code outputs

```
c/interleave as 1,44,2,55,66,77,88,0
```

Code:

```
public static int[] interleave(int[] a, int[] b)
 {
  int [] interleave = new int [a.length + b.length];
  int j = 0, k = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < (a.length + b.length);i++)
  {
     if (((i % 2 == 0) || (k >= b.length)) && (j < a.length))
     {
        interleave[i] = a[j];
        j++;
     }
     if (((i % 2 == 1) || (j >= a.length)) && (k < b.length))
     {
        interleave[i] = b[k];
        k++;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking `b.length` against `k` and `a.length` against `j`. Thus when `k` becomes `3` your second `if` will overwrite `interleave[i]` with `b[k]`. `k` and `j` should be switched:

```
if (((i % 2 == 0) || (j >= b.length)) && (j < a.length))
 {                 //^^^ 
    interleave[i] = a[j];
    j++;
 }
 if (((i % 2 == 1) || (k >= a.length)) && (k < b.length))
 {                  //^^^
    interleave[i] = b[k];
    k++;
 }
```

***Output:***

```
[1, 44, 2, 55, 3, 66, 77, 88]
```

Comment: Wow, sometimes I feel so dumb. I should've traced it again. It's so obvious. Thank you.

Comment: @StevenRummelhoff You can also fixing it by changing your two `if`'s to an `if- else if` (So if the first one is executed the second one won't also be executed and overwrite it)

Comment: Yeah, looking back, I asked myself if that mattered. there are so many layers to consider.